# Spinner Error when set setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

When i used spinner for dropdown list or `setOnItemSelectedListener` error occurs:

nav_login.xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:entries="@array/items" />
```

strinarray:

```
<string-array name="items">
    <item>Log Out</item>
    <item>Setting</item>
</string-array>
```

MainActivity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://intense-heat-4844.firebaseio.com/property");

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View mLoginButton = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
    mLoginButton.findViewById(R.id.Login);
    if (!myBooleanVariable) {
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Calling activity LoginRegister
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), LoginRegister.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (null != intent) {
        myBooleanVariable = intent.getBooleanExtra("my_boolean_key", myBooleanVariable);
        if (myBooleanVariable) {
            navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View mUserLoggedIn = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_login);


            final Spinner spinner;
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int arg2, long arg3) {
                    String msupplier = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    Log.e("Selected item : ", msupplier);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Spinner.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });



        }
    }

    ePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.Pager);
    ePager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    eTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.TabLayout);
    eTabs.setViewPager(ePager);

    Toolbartext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Toolbartext.setText("Residential Search");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    Navigation1 drawerfragment = (Navigation1)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation1);
    drawerfragment.setup(R.id.fragment_navigation1, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hitted item" + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Exception:

```
03-01 13:17:47.039    8587-8587/com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication I/System.out﹕ User ID: 4310e794-0b9b-4fad-afd0-e3f73c5f7412, Provider: password
03-01 13:17:47.074    8587-8587/com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-01 13:17:47.074    8587-8587/com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication, PID: 8587
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication/com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
```

Comment: Post your code completely, have you set `ContentView` ?

Comment: Do you have an activity named as a Spinner???

Comment: final Spinner spinner;
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

how this lines can be valid ? final varible can't be assigned this way

Comment: @csenga, it's a valid usage of final, compiler will figure that out

Comment: rebuild your project and check if you assigning the right root view (via setContentView)

Comment: i am doing this in MainActivity.java so SetContectView(activity_main) an i am using spinner as header so i donot setcontentview to spinner.

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera  
i am doing this in MainActivity.java so SetContectView(activity_main) an i am using spinner as header so i donot setcontentview to spinner.

Comment: @MickeyTin is it possible to set two "setcontentView();" in activity because i am using spinner in my MainActivity.java and this is because i am changing headrview when use is signed in.any help?

Comment: show your entire onCreate method. Make sure you call super.onCreate(saveInstanceState) as the first line in onCreate and make sure you setContentView before spinner logic

Comment: @MobileMon see the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use like this,
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
it will search for spinner in layout **activity_main** (since you set **activity_main** as a content view in onCreate) but it is not the child of **activity_main**. So it throw **NullPointerException**.

instead use like this,

spinner = (Spinner) **mUserLoggedIn**.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
(if spinner inside **nav_header_login** layout)

Comment: now it says:
 Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication/android.widget.Spinner}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: but my first item is clicked by default i want it to clicked by user @Kiran Rajam

Comment: by default means? does onItemSelected method execute automatically when you come to that screen

Comment: yes when draw is opened log out automatically executed because it is the first element in spinner

Comment: Okay just do this work around fix. While you add items to spinner add first item as "Select item" or something like this and then add remaining items. Now in onItemSelected method, insert this code . if(msupplier.equalsIgnoreCase("Select item")){  return;}

Comment: thanks i need you help in another thing i want layout to upload images:
Like fiverr where you upload images and it will show images in small view like the gallery view

Comment: If spinner error issue fixed with my answer please up vote that above comment, and close this question. And open new question for upload images issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's the problem. You set the contentView in OnCreate to R.layout.activity_main but the Spinner lives in nav_login.xml so program is looking for spinner in activity_main but can't find it.

2 Solutions:

1. Move the spinner from nav_login.xml to activity_main.xml

or

2. set content view to setContentView(R.layout.nav_login);

Comment: but i want my spinner to show in navigation drawer header that is not in the main_activity.xml